# The average of 10 scores is $25,$ and the lowest score is $20.$ So, the highest score must be...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, solution-verification, average, means

> The average score of $10$ students in a test is $25.$ The lowest score is $20.$ Then the highest score is:
> $$A.100,$$ $$B.70,$$ $$C.30,$$ $$D.75$$

The answer key suggests option $B$ as the answer. I don't understand why this differs from my solution:

Let the marks obtained by each student be $x_1,x_2,...,x_{10}$ and $S=\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i$.  Then, we have $\frac{S}{10}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i}{10}=20\implies S=200.$ If say, only one student obtained $25$, i.e let $x_k=25$, then, $$S-x_k=200-25=175.$$ Considering $S'=\sum_{i\neq k}x_i=175$. Now, if $\exists x_p=100$, then $100+(S'-x_p)=175\implies (S'-75)=75$, thus we are getting a situation, where it's possible for a student to score hundred, then, the rest students, will have to score, $75$ marks *in total.* This is the highest option given. Hence, the highest possible  score can be $100.$ *According to the information given, this can be a possible case, when 1 student scores 20, 8 students have a total score of  75 and one student scores 100, i.e then, average of this will still be 20.* So, option $A$ is correct.

Comment: Formatting tip:  If a superscript or subscript has more than one character, enclose it in curly braces.  For instance, typing `$x_{10}$` produces $x_{10}$, while typing `$\sum_{i = 1}^{10} x_i$` produces $\sum_{i = 1}^{10} x_i$.

Comment: Your solution is answering the question as though the given information is "The average score is 20 and at least one student scored 25". But the given information is that the average score is 25 and the *lowest* score is 20.

Comment: The lowest score is 20. This means all students scored at least 20, and the total score for any 8 students is at least $8\times 20=160$, so you cannot have 8 students with a total score of 75.

Comment: Since there are only ten students, it is not too lengthy a task to list all their scores one by one in a column. Write a column of scores that shows how you can obtain your solution. Just remember that the smallest number in the column must be $20$ and the average must be $25.$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignoring the typos, your solution is not making a lot of sense, and the overuse of symbols makes it less readable than it could have been.

Note that the question is incorrectly phrased: it should be asking for the **highest possible score**, not the highest score, because there is insufficient information to deduce the latter.

This happens when everyone else has obtained the lowest score $20,$ in which case those nine students have scored a total of $9\times20=180$ marks, in which case the top scorer has scored $10\times25-180=70$ marks.

---

On the other hand, to determine **possible highest score**, we observe that  the top score is minimum when $10\times25-20=230$ marks are equally distributed among the nine remaining students.

Hence, the top score must fall on the interval $$\left[25\frac59,70\right].$$

Comment: I don't get this. What I did was: I showed, if say, one student scores the lowest marks $25$ then the given conditions in the question makes it possible for a student to obtain $100$. *This can be a possible case, when 1 student scores 20, 8 students have a total score of  75 and one student scores 100, i.e then, average of this will still be 20* ?

Comment: @Arthur Why do you keep claiming that the lowest score is 25 despite being pointed out by at least two of us that it's 20? Or am I misunderstanding your misunderstanding? I don't understand your final sentence, a run-on sentence. $\quad$ Option B (greatest possible top score) corresponds to this scenario: $\{20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,70\};$ makes sense? $\quad$ On the other hand, the least possible top score corresponds to this scenario: $\{20,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 ,25\frac59 \}.$

Comment: Ah, that was a typo. My bad! Anyway, I got it. The mistake I was making that, I was forgetting no person can score less than 20....

Answer (score 2):

Average score of $25$ means that total score $S$ is $25\cdot 10 = 250$, not $200$.

If one of students scored at least $71$, and the rest scored at least $20$, then total score is at least $20 \cdot 9 + 71 = 251 > 250$. So no student scored higher than $70$.

However, both $B$ and $C$ are possible.

If $9$ students scored $20$ each and one scored $70$, then total score is $250$, as needed.

If $5$ students scored $20$ each and $5$ scored $30$ each, then again total score is $250$.

Actually, any score from $26$ to $70$ can be the highest.

Comment: I don't get what you mean : *According to the information given, this can be a possible case, when 1 student scores 20, 8 students have a total score of  75 and one student scores 100, i.e then, average of this will still be 20* ?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused: the sentence you cited is yours, not mine, and I didn't mean it. It is also wrong, because if $8$ students have total score of $75$, then at least one of them should have score less than $20$, but we are given that $20$ is lowest score anybody got.

Comment: No, no, you got me wrong ! I didn't cite it as yours. I am sorry if it appears to be so. I stated my own thoughts there. Yes, the comment I made was incorrect as I was forgetting the fact that no person could score less than $20$ . Sorry for the confusion. But, anyway, +1 from me for such a good answer. Thank you!